# Загрузка и отправка файла на почту PHP

Tags: php, email

Помогите добавить загрузку файла и его отправку на почту.

```
<?php
define("MAILTO" , "mail@mail.ru");
define("SUBJECT" , "Заголовок");
define("ERROR_MESSAGE" , "Ошибка при отправке сообщения");
$message = ' ';
$message .= 'От : ' . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n";
$message .= 'Email : ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
$headers = "От: ".$_POST['name']." <".$_POST['email'].">\r\n" ."Копия: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n";
function validateEmail($email) {
   if(preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", $email))
        return true;
   else
        return false;
}
if((strlen($_POST['name']) < 1 ) || (strlen($_POST['email']) < 1 ) || validateEmail($_POST['email']) == FALSE ) {
    echo( ERROR_MESSAGE );
} else {
    if( mail( MAILTO ,  SUBJECT , $message, $headers) ) {
        echo( "Отправлено" );
    } else {
        echo( ERROR_MESSAGE );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Попробовал PhpMailer и не понимаю почему письмо не приходит?  `<?php
require_once('PhpMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = $_POST['email'];
$email->FromName  = $_POST['name'];
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'adm@adm.ru' );

$file_to_attach = $_POST['file'];
$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , $_POST['file'] );
return $email->Send();
?>`

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

1. Файл куда-то должен скачаться. Проще всего задействовать cURL
   http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-exec.php
2. Дальше его надо прикрепить в письмо.
   2.1. Решение в лоб древним простым методом

```
    $message = "begin 644 $filename\n";
    $message.= convert_uuencode($file_content);
    $message .= "end\n";
```

2.2. Решение современным методом. Уже по ссылке http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php
направляет на PEAR пакет, который всё делает на отлично
http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime
Взять исходники, и можно остановиться на этом.

Comment: Проще всего file_get_contents да и в конце концов через форму с полем фаил а не curl непонятно от куда. Да и плюсом в вопросе хеадер в корне неправильный.

Comment: Я новичек, и не совсем понимаю это, к сожалению(